# How to i execute this two query in php?

Tags: php, mysql, database, sql-update

I am new in Stackoverflow and noob in programming.

I have a problem . I am creating a script that can change a database column info by give database username and password.

My source code is here :

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "admin";
$dbname = "mydb";
$password = "1234";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);


// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo "Connected successfully";
mysqli_select_db($conn,"$dbname");


$sql = "UPDATE users SET login='admin1' WHERE id=1";
$sql2 = "UPDATE users SET pass='1234' WHERE id=1";


if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();

?>
```

Now there is two query's

```
$sql = "UPDATE users SET login='admin1' WHERE id=1";  
$sql2 = "UPDATE users SET pass='1234' WHERE id=1";
```

How can I execute this two query's and i want that when this two query's became true I message will be show that Record updated successfully. In the above source code showing error.

Comment: Official documentation (or even just a google search) is the best place to start: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html

Comment: Just a hint for beginning: Never ever store a password in plain text inside your database. Never unless you really have a really good reason for. Use e.g. salted hashes instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can update both records by one query:

```
$sql = "UPDATE users 
        SET login = 'admin1',
            pass  = '1234' 
        WHERE id = 1";
```

Comment: I want to take database name,password,host and database changed value from user how to do this????  Jens/Loot/panther/singh

Comment: please add this as a new query or add this in your above question, then only you will get answer. better to go with new question with some example code. Also if you got answer then your responsibility is to vote up best suitable answer, so that it helps other in future.

Answer (score 0):

Do it in one query:

```
$sql = "UPDATE users SET login='admin1', pass='1234'  WHERE id=1";
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are updating one table, you can have one query instead like this:

```
$sql = "UPDATE users SET login='admin1',pass='1234'  WHERE id=1";
```

Comment: this will not work if he have two different type of sql query like UPDATE AND SELECT.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
$sql = "UPDATE users " 
       . " SET login='admin1',pass='1234' " 
       . " WHERE id=1";
```