# How to activate multiple query arrays at once?

Tags: php

I have multiple array queries, but I want to write a code where I can convert al the queries into 1 long query.

```
if(in_array($_POST[$veldnaam],$idarr))
{
   $queries[] = "UPDATE ".$dba."config SET value='".$_POST[$veldnaam]."' WHERE id='".$idarr[$veldnaam]."' AND code='".$CONFIG['site_id']."')"; 
}   
else 
{
   $queries[] = "INSERT INTO ".$dba."config (`code`,`key`,`value`) VALUES ('".$CONFIG['site_id']."','".$veldnaam."','".$_POST[$veldnaam]."')" ; 
}

}
else
{
}   
}
else
{
   $queries[] = "INSERT INTO ".$dba."config (`code`,`key`,`value`) VALUES ('".$CONFIG['site_id']."','".$veldnaam."','".$_POST[$veldnaam]."')";
            }
        }
    }
// convert queries into 1 long query
```

Comment: Do you really need one query? You can also just foreach through the array and query these then.

Comment: You can execute multiple updates or inserts in the same query. It shouldn't be an issues. However your code is not complete here. You should also consider using prepared statements. As it stands your code is pretty vulnerable to sql injection.

Comment: Check my answer in this link :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28958844/how-to-i-execute-this-two-query-in-php/28958924#28958924. hope it help you.

Comment: code formatting , still have code errors

Comment: @warn: mysql injection detected ;)
Also when combining queries you need the ending `;` to tell sql it's the end of the query.

Comment: Why not something like `$db->multi_query( implode(";", $queries) );` See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6461110/3000179